# Domain account keeps getting locked out

Tags: active-directory, password

Is there a way to determine why my domain account keeps getting locked out?  I keep finding myself locking my machine then coming back, trying to log in and getting the "Your account has been locked out" message.  I keep having to have IT reset my password.

Comment: How about asking IT?

Comment: Agree with GregD, this should be something you should be discussing with your IT department.  There are event logs and security policies to consider for troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 2):

One cause could be if you're account is configured to run some kind of task or service at an interval and the credentials cached on that task/service are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Check out EventComb from Microsoft.  Not sure what your rights on the domain are, but this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824209)  tells how to use it to search the event logs on the Domain Controller for account lockouts among other things.  We just used this tool to find out which machine was locking out a user who was getting locked out several times a day and didn't know why.  Download is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7AF2E69C-91F3-4E63-8629-B999ADDE0B9E&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

One other possibilty is that you have a mapped drive that has cached credentials that are invalid.  The system keeps trying to connect and finally is locked out for bad attempts. Basically similar to the scheduled task or service mentioned by Chis W

Always a good idea to ask the admin as they have the needed tools as noted.